# Cannot deselect all optionsof a multi-select if the option "All" is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0b4j5o8/30/)

I am having this problem(the dropdown is using **chosen** pluggin)

I am calling a jquery function. The issue is, there is a multiselect with the first option being "**All**" and all the other options are present

When the "**All**" will be selected, then all the other options will be deselected.

### Here's my multi-select:

```
    <select id="risk_mitigator_offer_1" name="risk_mitigator_offer_1[]" 
       class="input_field criteria_risk" style="width:302px;" 
       multiple onchange="checkAll(this)">
       <option value="All">All</option>
       <?php
       $offers_off = array();
       $_sql_off = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM mt_offers WHERE camp_id=' . $mysql['camp_id'] . ' AND deleted = "0" ORDER BY offer_id' );
       if ($_sql_off) 
       {
         while ($_data_off = mysql_fetch_assoc( $_sql_off )) 
         {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_data_off['offer_id']?>"><?php echo $_data_off['offer_name'];?></option>
   <?php  }
       } ?>  
    </select>
```

### And here's is the jquery function:

```
function checkAll(obj)
{
    var values = $(obj).val();
    if (values) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
        {
            if(values[i] == "All")
            {
                $(obj+" option[value!=All]").removeAttr("selected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Now the problem is that,I am getting the following jquery error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLSelectElement] option[value!=All]


throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
```

How can I fix this issue?

I know it may be a silly one,the issue is in this line of code:

```
$(obj+" option[value!=All]").removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `obj` is an [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) object, so you can't construct CSS selector by concatenating strings like your are trying to do. Instead filter all options except "All" and unselect them with prop method:

```
function checkAll(obj) {
    var values = $(obj).val();
    if (values) {
        $(obj).find('option').filter(function() {
            return this.value !== 'All';
        }).prop('selected', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is wrong.. when I am selecting any option, even if its not "All",then also the current option is getting selected and the rests are getting deselected

Comment: @Saswat That's because select / option is for single selection. Maybe you could make use of checkboxes since those are for multiple select.

Comment: @NewToJS  its a multi-select bro

Comment: @Saswat my apologies, I didn't see `multiple` in the select element. -facepalms-

Comment: Wrong? This is a fixed version of your own function with its original business logic.

Comment: @dfsq, my apologies, I actually want it based on the fiddle example I have provided.... Select All, and all the other options will be disabled in the dropdown list... Check my fiddle to understand what I said